# SSH Keys are working in Terminal but not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I Have a SSH key. I need to send some files to the GCP instance. Using scp to do that. It's working fine in terminal in ubuntu.

```html
gcloud compute scp --recurse LOCAL_DIR_PATH INSTANCENAME:REMOTE_FOLDER_PATH --ssh-key-file=SSHKEY_PATH/SSHPRIVATEKEY
```

When i run this in my terminal working fine.
When i wrote this in Jenkins pipeline script

```html
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
                    sh '''
                        gcloud compute scp --recurse LOCAL_DIR_PATH INSTANCENAME:REMOTE_FOLDER_PATH --ssh-key-file=SSHKEY_PATH/SSHPRIVATEKEY
                    '''
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is giving this error

```
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud is not readable.
WARNING: Your SSH key files are broken.
private key (BROKEN) [SSHKEY_PATH/PRIVATEKEY]
public key  (OK)     [SSHKEY_PATH/PUBLICKEY]
```

Can Anyone Help me out?

Comment: On which operating system did you create the keypair and by what method? Use vi/vim and check the keypair file format `:set ff?`

Comment: I created the keypair in Ubuntu System 
command i used is 

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f PATH/KEY_FILENAME -C USERNAME -b 2048`

Comment: Is the file local to your home directory? The error message says **not readable**. Maybe you have a user/permission issue when running under Jenkins.

Comment: It's likely the file isn't even there. insert a step that does `file SSHKEY_PATH/SSHPRIVATEKEY`.  you will likely see "cannot open `fff' (No such file or directory)".  solve that problem